# IE9 link hover css color change vertical shift

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

IE 9 on Hover over a link, pushes some of the HTML down the page.
When i remove the color from

```
td.subarea > h2 > a:hover   { color: #aa051a; text-decoration: none;}
```

the problem does not occur.

I can't paste all the code here, and fairly sure its a unique problem to this page.
But maybe someone out there has seen something similar.

Its not moving the Link(a tag) down the page, its the whole containing table that moves.

Comment: Going to have to provide us with more info than 1 line of generic css, there could be a wide variety of things causing this in your code completely unrelated to that color property.

Comment: If something moves on hover, then that hover changes is causing the width of an element to change. Maybe there's a 1px difference in a border, or some text goes slightly wider, which causes a pixel-perfect floated layout to suddenly break, because now it's 901px instead of 900px (or whatever).

Answer (score 9):

This problem seems to occur in IE9 when the container element is set to `overflow: auto` and there is some hover action taking place in the child element.

There is a very simple solution of adding `min-height: 0px` to the container element, which works.

The detailed explanation of the bug and this solution can be found in this link:
http://blog.brianrichards.net/post/6721471926/ie9-hover-bug-workaround

Comment: Very subtle difference, but `min-height: 0px` as cited in this answer does not work for me. However, `min-height: 0%` as cited in the linked article works perfectly when applied to the element with overflow that is increasing in size.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your line-height and font-size properties are the same for normal and hover.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of found the problem, well makes the table stop moving. margin-top:-20px.
Although it olny shifted down about 10px.

Probably some IE9 rendering issue. IE7/8 actually move the table on intial loading.

The font sizes, line-heights, all that css, is all good for the link.

Marc B is probably close to the issue of IE rendering something wrong and cauing floats and such to mess up.

Now have to real style a table layout wihtin a table layout page(ugh, hate table layout).

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to specify

```
height:100%;
```

Then I had to go ahead and specify

```
width:100%;
```

The 'min-height: 0px' by mohitp above got me on the right track.

Comment: Did you try min-height: 0%;?  0px didn't work for me but 0% did.  Damn issue continues to exist in IE11, too!

Comment: I didn't try that, nor do I remember what I was working on that had the problem now. I should really add a clue for myself somewhere.