# Jitter on DIV Hover with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I just cant seem to fix this issue where on hover, the DIV expands and then shrinks giving a "jumpy" or "jitter" look. This only seems to happen in IE 11 and I cant pinpoint why.

I have a list which will be for images and I want the hover state to be a block that is 10px less than its parent;

[Here is my fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/P6JGY/1381/)

Here is my code;

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<li class="item w2 h2"> <div class="inner"></div></li>
<li class="item w2 h2"> <div class="inner"></div></li>
<li class="item w2 h2"> <div class="inner"></div></li>
<li class="item w2 h2"> <div class="inner"></div></li>
<li class="item w2 h2"> <div class="inner"></div></li>
<li class="item w2 h2"> <div class="inner"></div></li>
</div>
```

CSS - the inner class is the one with the hover

```
#container {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.item {
  display:block !important;
  list-style:none;
  float: left;
  background: #CCC;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.item.w2 { width: 300px; }
.item.h2 { height: 200px; }

.inner {
    background:#fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;

}

.inner:hover  {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=95)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
    opacity: .95;
    z-index:1;
}


/* no transition on .isotope container */

.isotope .isotope-item {
  /* change duration value to whatever you like */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
          transition-duration: .6s;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
     -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
          transition-property:         transform, opacity;
    opacity:.5;
}
```

Consequently the "jumpy" or "jitter" disappears when there is no -transition such as ease-in-out or opacity.

I appreciate anyone who has a look! any suggestions would be great this is a huge learning curve for me :)

Comment: If you have issue only on IE 11 - mention this on your question. Edit it.

Comment: I checked your fiddle in Chrome 30.0.1599.101m on Win7x64. I don't see any problems. Chrome tends to have different behavior on 32-bit systems. Please add details about your system.

Comment: i accidentally put this as chrome when it was actually IE causing the issue. My apologies!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  It has something to do with the :hover/opacity.  Looking into it further.  !#$% IE!

Comment: Here is a much simpler demo of the problem.  No position css at all.  http://jsfiddle.net/DqUvL/3/  opacity, margin, float, clear attributes.  Not rocket science.

Comment: Reported as a bug to microsoft:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/813487/layout-issues-related-to-opacity-float-clear-margins

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE9 link hover css color change vertical shift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445750/ie9-link-hover-css-color-change-vertical-shift)

Answer (score 0):

I created a simplified example of this problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/DqUvL/14/

I also reported the problem to MSFT:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/107987/

HTML:

```
<a class="bad" href="#">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" alt="cat">
  <div class="detail">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div class="margin">
      Margin
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</a><a class="bad" href="#">
  <div class="detail">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.bad {
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.bad:hover {
  outline-color: red;
}
img {
  float:left;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
.margin {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

I worked around the problem by adding a **container style="overflow:hidden"** around the hover elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/DqUvL/16/

This solves the simplified problem.

Thanks @mohitp:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665222/973470

Answer (score -1):

I tested with IE 10. Seems that your divs are too big, because they have `position: absolute`.
Therefore they are aligned to the `container`. Add this to your `item` class:

```
.item {
  position: relative;
}
```

Absolute elements are aligned to the next parent that is not `static`. It might be that IE's default stylesheet differs from the other browsers when it comes to list elements position. Did not checked this yet.